# Adding tags, headers and etc. to existing PDF with iText7

Tags: accessibility, birt, itext7

I'm working with PDF on tags for accessibility with iText7. I get PDF via BIRT's template from DB  and can't to add tags there.
Are there any ways in the iText7 to add tags automatically?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is going to work.
Generally speaking, you cannot add tags automatically to an existing PDF.
So, as of now, BIRT cannot create tagged PDF.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Keep trying to find a solution to modify existing PDF, to read and re-write with tags. Or maybe, BIRT uses iText to create PDF, just replace libraries.